# How to create com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap

Tags: scala, guava

```
val map = com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap[String, Int].create()
```

gives the compile error

```
object com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap is not a value
```

How do I create an instance of `com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of where you put the type parameters. Try

```
val map = HashBiMap.create[String, Int]()
```

Answer (score 2):

The class `HashBiMap` has two generic type parameters. Its companion object (the object that shares the name `HashBiMap`) does not have type parameters, because it's an object, not a class. When you call `HashBiMap.create`, you're calling the `create` method on the companion object. So, the expression `HashBiMap[String, Int].create` doesn't make any sense, because that `HashBiMap` refers to the object, which isn't parameterized. Its `create` method, does take two type parameters. So `HashBiMap.create[String, Int]()` does what you want. It returns a `HashBiMap[String, Int]`.

In case you're more familiar with Java: The expression you've given is akin to something like `Arrays<Integer>.asList(1,2,3)`, whereas the correct expression would be `Arrays.<Integer>asList(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Yes, and I seem to always make the same mistake in Java :P

Comment: At least Scala's syntax is more consistent (the types always go after the thing you're parameterizing).

Comment: It does make sense, since `object` does not have type parameters, but the method does.